# Print values of void pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void

I have a funciton that returns a void pointer. Lets say I know that the block of data pointed at is an array of ints. How can I print them?

From another thread I saw that I cast the void as my desired data type this way:

```
printf("%i",*((int*)data));
```

But like I said that data is an array of ints. I tried to do this, but it's not a valid expression:

```
for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
    printf("%i \n", *((int*)(data+sizeof(int)*i)));
}
```

What is the proper way of printing this?

Comment: `int *ptr = void_pointer;` and then just use `ptr`. (You can also write `*((int*)data + i)`, but having an `int*` to use is less error-prone.)

Comment: By the way, `*((int *)data + i)` is perfectly valid and correct (although not at all readable).

Comment: @H2CO3 More readable than `*(int*)((char*)data + i*sizeof(int))`, isn't it? ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Preparing for the 2014 IOCCC or what? ;-)

Comment: @H2CO3 No, just being a bit silly, had maybe a beer too much this evening.

Comment: Why not `((int*)data)[i]`?

Comment: @KerrekSB (I guess it's too mainstream...)

Answer (score 8):

Just use a temporary `int*`:

```
int *p = data;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    printf("%i\n", p[i]);
```

Note that there's no explicit cast in the first line, because that's not needed with `void*` and avoiding explicit casts is considered good C style. Inside the loop, I've used the fact that you can index into a pointer to an array as if it were the array itself.

Answer (score 4):

Your original attempt is incorrect in "formal" C, since pointer arithmetic is not applicable to `void *` pointers. However, some compilers support pointer arithmetic on `void *` pointers as a non-standard extension (GCC being a notable example). In such compilers `void *` pointers are treated as `char *` pointers for arithmetic purposes. And your

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%i\n", *((int *) (data + sizeof(int) * i)));
```

will actually work as intended in such compiler.

With a more pedantic compiler, you can save the day by doing

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%i\n", *((int *) ((char *) data + sizeof(int) * i)));
```

But in any case, the above two pieces of code are hopelessly overcomplicated. They have some value as examples when you are just learning pointer arithmetic, but that's about all they are good for.

What you really need is just

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%i\n", ((int *) data)[i]);
```

You can introduce an extra `int *` pointer, as other answers suggested, to make your code even more readable. But that's up to you.